# How can I make a css gradient like this and mouseover border

Tags: jquery, html, css, gradient

I need help replicating three buttons like these, I am most concerned about how to make the gradient look exactly like how they are. I am also curious as to how put a white border on mouse over or button click

I tried this code for the gradient but all I get is a thick white line though the middle. Any help will be appreciated

```css
#blue{
  background: linear-gradient(#00a1d6, white , #00a1d6);
}
#yellow{
  background: linear-gradient(#df8700, white , #df8700);
}
#red{
  background: linear-gradient(#950f16, white , #950f16);
}
```

[image: Three squares gradient]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your DOM is constructed you may want to avoid using borders as sometimes the border thickness will shift elements around on the screen.  Try using box-shadow.

```css
#blue:hover,
#yellow:hover,
#red:hover,
#blue:active,
#yellow:active,
#red:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 2px white;
}
```

Or give each button a class to simplify the css

```css
.button-class:hover,
.button-class:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 2px white;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".square"/*button class or id*/).hover(function(){
    $(this).css("border","2px solid #fff;")
},function(){
    $(this).css("border","none")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#color {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

You probably want something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, after playing around with it I came up with the solution.

```
#color{
    background: ... (#00a1d6 0%, #55b7d6 45% , #00a1d6 0%);
      }
```